# Displaying a 2D array of integers as an image in Java

Tags: java, arrays, graphics, integer, 2d

I'm trying to create an application in Java that will print an image based on an array of integers where each integer represents a color. Is there a straightforward way to accomplish this?

```
public void displayImage(int[][] arr){
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < arr[0].length; j++){
            switch(arr[i][j]){
                case 1:
                //print a gray pixel at (i, j) within a frame
                case 0:
                //print a green pixel at (i, j) within a frame
                case 2:
                //print a white pixel at (i, j) within a frame
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`BufferedImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html), as shown in this [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/raster).

Addendum: The example cited updates the image's underlying [`WritableRaster`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/WritableRaster.html) using an `int` array of color components, but [`setRGB()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#setRGB%28int,%20int,%20int%29) is convenient if the color is already available.

Comment: This example is easy to follow. I think this example solved my problem.

Comment: A related example using `SwingWorker` is shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24977111/230513).