# Retrieving data from a map when using a SwingWorker

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface, swingworker

I have a class that creates a GUI and has a `JComboBox` with an ItemListener.  On an `ItemEvent.Selected` event I create the worker and try to read data into a map, but the contents is always empty.

My guess is that this is happening due to the thread executing and leaving the `ItemListener` before the thread completes.

I've added relevant pieces of my code and hoping you guys can help me determine where the issue is.

```
private void updateUI(String text) {

   StringUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

      @Override 
      public void run() {
          text.append(text + "\n");
      }
   }
}

private class ComboBoxListener extends ItemListener {

@Override
public void itemStateChange(ItemEvent e) {

   if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED) { return; }
   if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {

       //do stuff
       Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

       new MyWorker(var1, var2) {

          @Override
          public updateUI(String text) {
               updateMainUI(text);
          } 

          @Override
          public updateMap(String name, String value) {
              map.put(name, value);
          }
       }.execute();

       for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
          // do something with map contents
       }
     }
   }
}
```

The `updateUI` and `updateMap` are abstract methods in `MyWorker` that I'm overriding so that I can send updates to the gui.

In short, how can I get the data back from the worker so that I can execute it *before* the event is done?

I wrote most of this from memory since I don't have the actual code in front of me at the moment, so please ignore minor typos and syntax issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) executes its `doInBackground()` method asynchronously on another thread; the results will become available at indeterminate times in the future, but you're examining the map entries immediately. Instead, `publish()` each `Map.Entry<String, String>` as it becomes available in `doInBackground()` and `process()` the values  as they become available.

If the intermediate results can be usefully displayed in another component, update that component's model, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4637725/230513) for the text of a `JLabel`. If not, override `done()` to use the completed result, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44981400/230513) for an `Icon`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  This is a very helpful suggestion.  I guess neglected to add some important details.  The listener that calls the worker thread populates a jlist and that list can't be populated until the worker thread has completed.  So in a sense, my listener shouldn't be finished until the worker has completed and populated the jlist.

Comment: Should my jlist somehow be updated in my worker class and not wait until after the worker thread completes?

Comment: You can incrementally update the `ListModel` in `process()`, which runs on the EDT, and the listening `JList` will update itself. Alternatively, update the `ListModel` in `done()`, which also runs on the EDT