# How to convert a 2d array of integers to an image in java?

Tags: java, arrays, graphics, integer, 2d

I have an array of positive integers. How would I display this as an image? I do not already the range of values that the array contains or the size of the array. A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251791/displaying-a-2d-array-of-integers-as-an-image-in-java). But I do not know the possible values without searching a possibly very large array. What is the best way of doing this with regards to efficiency and length of code?

Here is a small example of what the data could be

```
    0   2   4   6   8   10  12  14  16
    2   2   6   6   10  10  14  14  18
    4   6   4   6   12  14  12  14  20
    6   6   6   6   14  14  14  14  22
    8   10  12  14  8   10  12  14  24
   10   10  14  14  10  10  14  14  26
   12   14  12  14  12  14  12  14  28
   14   14  14  14  14  14  14  14  30
   16   18  20  22  24  26  28  30  16
   18   18  22  22  26  26  30  30  18
```

Comment: What file format are you shooting for? A BMP image header would be the first 14 bytes of your array I think.

Comment: I do not care that much about the file format unless it decreases the efficiency considerably.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21576096/convert-a-2d-array-of-doubles-to-a-bufferedimage).

```
int xLenght = arr.length;
int yLength = arr[0].length;
BufferedImage b = new BufferedImage(xLenght, yLength, 3);

for(int x = 0; x < xLenght; x++) {
    for(int y = 0; y < yLength; y++) {
        int rgb = (int)arr[x][y]<<16 | (int)arr[x][y] << 8 | (int)arr[x][y]
        b.setRGB(x, y, rgb);
    }
}
ImageIO.write(b, "Doublearray", new File("Doublearray.jpg"));
System.out.println("end");
```

Now, refactor this code to read a proper input.

Comment: Can you vote up for the answer when it was useful to you? :)

Comment: I tried that but I just joined today so my reputation is less than 15. :-(